# Mathematical Induction and Algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In a question taken from Discrete Mathematic With Applications

A question tries to prove $2^{2n}-1$ is divisible by 3.

In the solution it has 
$$2^{2k}(3+1)-1$$
$$2^{2k}.3+(2^{2k}-1)$$
What happened to the 1 in (3+1) ? are they saying 1 was equivalent to $2^{2k}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They just expanded the term with the first term by multiplying out the parentheses:

$$2^{2k}(3+1)-1=2^{2k}(3)+2^{2k}(1)-1=2^{2k}(3)+(2^{2k}-1)$$

Comment: Wow .... my basic mathematics understanding are being tested in Induction . Thanks for answer

Answer (score 1):

$2^{2n}= 4^n$. But $4\equiv1\pmod3$ Hence $2^{2n}\equiv 1\pmod 3$.

Comment: Is it true that $4=1(mod 3)$ implies $4^n=1 ^n (mod 3)$? Take $n=2$.

Comment: A basic property of congruences is that $a\equiv b\pmod m,\ c\equiv d\pmod m$ implies $ac\equiv bd\pmod m$.

Comment: @ Babai: Yes $4^2=16$, when divided by 3 gives remainder 1.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right!

Answer (score 0):

No, $1$ is not equivalent to $2^{2k}$. But the dsitributive law says that $2^{2k}(3+1)=3\cdot 2^{2k}+2^{2k}$. Now substract $-1$ from it. In case you want to prove that this is divisible by $3$ by induction, then see [this MSE-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648273/prove-by-induction-that-22n-1-is-divisible-by-3-whenever-n-is-a-positiv).