# What is a good example of a proof whose technique is extreme overkill for the problem being solved?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, big-list

What are some proofs that are inappropriately powerful for the problem being solved? (Something like the math equivalent of using an atom bomb to kill a spider)

Comment: Like this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648273/prove-by-induction-that-22n-1-is-divisible-by-3-whenever-n-is-a-positiv/1622941#1622941?

Comment: There is a whole post on that [mathoverflow.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42512/awfully-sophisticated-proof-for-simple-facts)

Comment: $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is irrational.  Suppose not.  Then there are $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $$\sqrt[3]{2} = p/q \implies 2 = p^3/q^3 \implies q^3 + q^3 = p^3, $$ which contracticts Fermat-Wiles.

Answer (score 6):

**Problem:** Prove that, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}$, $\sqrt[n]{2}$ is irrational.

**Proof:** There is a very well-known proof for the case $n=2$. Suppose that $n>2$. If there were two natural numbers $p$ and $q$ such that $\sqrt[n]2=\frac pq$, then$$p^n=2q^n=q^n+q^n.$$This is impossible by Wiles' theorem (a.k.a. Fermat's last theorem).

Comment: Bah! Beat me to it by 20 seconds (and in greater generality).  ;) (+1)

Comment: But you have to make sure we can prove FLT without using the irrationality of $2^{1/n}$ anywhere.

Comment: @user37208 I would be amazed if the proof used that fact, but I must admit that I did not check it.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos let’s email wiles and ask him ;)

Answer (score 2):

Russell and Whitehead's proof that $1+1=2$ that took several hundreds of pages of lemma's in Principia Mathematica comes to mind.

I don't know if *inappropriate* is the right word in this case, since of course the very idea of P.M. was to show that you can build a lot of mathematics on top of very elementary axioms of logic and set theory, but it definitely feels like shooting a mice with a cannon.